# Deadlock caused by using window api critical setion and event

Tags: c++, winapi

Thread 1

...
    `SetEvent(_event)`;

```
EnterCriticalSection(crit);

ResetEvent(_event);

LeaveCriticalSection(crit);
```

Thread 2:

```
EnterCriticalSection(crit);

WaitForSingleObject(_event, forever);

LeaveCriticalSection(crit);
```

When Thread 1 set Event, the Thread 2 is still waiting and wait forever. So, Thead 1 try to get the lock, but fail to deadlock. I check the return value of SetEvent which is OK.

I remove the EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection of thread 1, and find that the event is still unset after lots of times calling of SetEvent

Comment: It would help to know what specific problem you're trying to solve with events and critical sections. Deadlocks are a sign of a bad problem solution.

Comment: Thead 1 is main thread of UI system. Thread 2 is one of working thread. I click a button on the UI, and want to wake the working thread to do some  work . I use the event and lock as above to keep the correct things will be done.But, after I click the button, I find that the threads is deadlock with the status : Thread 1 is waiting the critical section lock and Thread 2 is still waiting for event.

Comment: is thread 2 the only thread waiting on the event? is it a manual reset or an auto reset event? is any of this in a loop?

Comment: because thread 2 is waiting for event in critical section, then thread 1 can't reset the event because it can't enter into the critical section (since thread 2 is in). you should remove critical sections if they only are protecting event and waitforsingleobject, since, well, they don't have to be protected

Comment: Yes, the only thread,A manual reset.

Comment: If you removed the CS in thread 1, did you also remove the ResetEvent? (you should have)

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to wrap an event with a critical section. The event provides adequate thread synchronization by itself, so get rid of the critical section altogether.

Thread 1

```
SetEvent(_event); // Or PulseEvent(), depending on the nature of the event
```

Thread 2:

```
WaitForSingleObject(_event, forever);
```

That is all you need.

Comment: Yes, I remove the critical section and try. But I find more suprising problem. I add it to the question.

Comment: If it's a manual reset event then you need to reset it yourself (you would normally do this following the `WaitForSingleObject`).